# Disable import of Richfaces 4 CSS

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I tried to disable the skinning of my components using Richfaces 4 in my JSF 2 application. So there's my **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>plain</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This makes my application not to be skinned with the Richfaces 4 default skin. But when I add a Richfaces component, it still gets those classes set. Would that be possible to disable those CSS, without overriding all of the Richfaces CSS classes ?

Comment: I didn't find any solution to my problem, so I had to override Richfaces style sheets, which is a shame in my opinion :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok first of all org.richfaces.**SKIN** from RF 3 has been replaced with org.richfaces.**skin** of RF 4 (notice the lowercase).

Secondly org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy is not supported in RF 4. Try going through [Richfaces migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-Skinning)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `org.richfaces.enableControlSkinningClasses` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you for answering Kumar. I've just tried your solution but this doesn't work for me.